# how to access current instance method in included module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, include

Suppose I have some

```
class Generator
      attr_accessor :param1
      attr_accessor :param2

      def initialize(param1, param2)
          @param1 = param1
          @param2 = param2
      end
      include Command
```

and in `Command`

```
module Command
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      def self.included(klass)
        @path ||=klass.new(@param1,@param2) unless (@param1.nil? && @@param2.nil?)
      end
```

Suppose I create some `Generator.new(param1,param2)`, then @param1 and `@param2` are nil when included by module. How can I get these values inside `included` method ?

Comment: This logic doesn't entirely make sense to me.  It appears that you want to set the `@path` instance variable to point to another instance of the same class at initialization (and doing it wrong to boot).  Is that what you are looking to do?  Why?  Also, you have a typo - `@@param2` instead of `@param2`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to set `@path` instance variable of `Generator` instance, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MarekLipka in fact, I have several classes that includes command, and I want each of them to share the `path` instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are not clear about a number of things. Your `initialize` method was probably meant to say:

```
 @param1 = law
 @param2 = current_user
```

But aside from that, it seems you don't understand what a `included` hook is and when it is called. Your `included` hook will only be called once, when the `include Command` line in `Generator` is executed. By the time you create a new `Generator` with `Generator.new(param1,param2)`, your `included` hook has already been called and will not be called again.

As a friendly suggestion, if you are a beginner with Ruby, I would suggest using the basic features of the language and getting to know them well before you try making use of things like `included` hooks and so on.